# Why we need "nodenext" typescript compiler option when we have "esnext"?

Tags: node.js, typescript

In the typescript compiler options [#module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) we've a bunch of options including `nodenext` and `esnext`, where `nodenext` is experimental (as of now).

Why we need this additional `nodenext` option when the `esnext` option seem already working with node.js?

Or rephrased in other words, what is the difference between `nodenext` and `esnext`?

---

source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46452#issuecomment-1066771513

Comment: What Node supports and what's in the spec are overlapping but not 1:1 concepts.

Comment: From TypeScript 5.2, it is not possible to configure "esnext" using Node's module resolution. You will have to set "module" to "nodenext": https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-rc/#module-and-moduleresolution-must-match-under-recent-node-js-settings

Answer (score 146, accepted):

### `module` and `moduleResolution`

The first thing that needs clarification is the difference the `module` and `moduleResolution` compiler options. The former is an emit setting: what module-related code will tsc be willing to emit to JS? The easiest way to see the effect of this option is by toggling between settings `commonjs` and `esnext`:

| Input code | Output `--module commonjs` | Output `--module esnext` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `import { createSourceFile } from "typescript"` | `"use strict"; Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); const typescript_1 = require("typescript");` | `import { createSourceFile } from "typescript"` |

While this setting fundamentally controls emit, it can impose limitations on what module-related input code is allowed. For example, you cannot write imports in the style of `import fs = require("fs")` under `--module es2015` (or higher ES targets) because there is no `require` to speak of in the ES module system. Additionally, using top-level `await` is only allowed in `--module es2022` (or higher) or `system` because it requires corresponding support in the module loading system.

On the other hand, `--moduleResolution` is all about the algorithm used to answer the question “given a file system and some input file containing an import from `"lodash"`, what files should I look for to find that module?” Obviously, the decision to look in a folder with a magical name `node_modules` is one related to Node (albeit one that a huge amount of non-Node tooling has copied for convenience), and is not going to be correct for every possible runtime.

### Differences in `moduleResolution`

With this context, we’re ready to begin answering your question directly. The biggest, most noticeable difference between `--module nodenext` and `--module esnext` is that the former implies `--moduleResolution nodenext`, a new resolution mode designed for Node’s specific implementation of co-existing ESM and CJS, while the latter *does not imply a `moduleResolution` setting because there is no such corresponding setting in TypeScript right now.* Put another way, when you say you’re using `--module esnext`, you’re allowed to write, and we will emit, the latest and greatest ES module code constructs, but we will not do anything differently with deciding how imports resolve. You’ll likely continue using `--moduleResolution node`, which was designed for Node’s implementation of CJS. What does this mean for you? If you’re writing ESM for Node, you can probably make some stuff work with `--module esnext` and `--moduleResolution node`, but newer Node-specific features like [package.json exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) won’t work, and it will be extremely easy to shoot yourself in the foot when writing import paths. Paths will be evaluated by tsc under Node’s CJS rules, but then at runtime, Node will evaluate them under its ESM rules since you’re emitting ESM. There are significant differences between these algorithms—notably, the latter requires relative imports to use file extensions instead of dropping the `.js`, and `index` files have no special meaning, so you can’t import the index file just by naming the path to the directory.

### Differences in `module`

The difference observable in the `--module` setting itself is a bit more subtle. As I mentioned before, in `esnext` you aren’t allowed to write `import Foo = require("bar")` because we assume there is no `require`. In `nodenext`, we know that a given module might be an ES module *or* it might be a CJS module, based on its file extension (`.mts` → `.mjs` implies ESM and `.cts` → `.cjs` implies CJS) and/or the `type` field in the nearest package.json file. `--module nodenext` enables looking at these things to make decisions about what kind of module a given file is, which controls what kind of module output we emit. If the aforementioned conditions result in a module being interpreted as CJS, the output for that file is nearly identical (maybe identical?) to what you’d get from `--module commonjs`. If the module is interpreted as ESM, the output is very similar to what you’d get from `--module esnext`, with one exception I can recall off the top of my head: you’re still allowed to write `import Foo = require("bar")`, and that gets compiled to:

```
import { createRequire as _createRequire } from "module";
const __require = _createRequire(import.meta.url);
const Foo = __require("bar");
```

### Summary

I think the answer to your question can be summarized like this:

- Node 12+ has support for CJS and ESM side-by-side, indicated by package.json `type` and special file extensions, so we need a module emit mode that understands that stuff. That mode can be thought of roughly as a Node-based selector between the existing `commonjs` and `esnext` modes, with a few additional little differences tailored to Node.
- Node 12+ also brings major new features to how module specifiers in packages can resolve, and enforces a different and much stricter resolution algorithm specifically for ESM imports. Without a matching TypeScript resolution mode, we both fail to resolve in the face of those new features and let you write paths that *won’t* resolve in ESM resolution.

Comment: did your part in moduleResolution also cover import maps and bar specifier resolve wich is part of the spec in general? which again makes it compatible via esModuleInterOp default.

Comment: This is interesting, and it matches the TypeScript 4.7-beta announcement on the Microsoft devblogs.  However, I'm trying to replicate this and having problems.  Namely, I have a test package, using TypeScript 4.7.0-beta, with `tsconfig.json` containing `module` set to `nodenext`.  A file with `.cts` is not being compiled to `.cjs`, neither `.mts` compiled to `.mjs`.  The package has three files, `cts.cts`, `index.ts`, and `mts.mts`.  All three are compiled to the same format - either CJS or MJS depending on setting - while the file extension does become either `.cjs` or `.js` or `.mts`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew for all the work you put into that answer. It's incredibly helpful.

Comment: @Andrew when I `import { CharStream } from 'antlr4'` it fails to resolve with `moduleResolution: 'nodenext'`. Why could that be?  `antlr4` has `"type": "module"`, `"main"` pointing to an ESM `.js` file, and `"types"` pointing to the type defs.  It doesn't have an export map.  Does `nodenext` resolution always ignore the `types` field?

Comment: 2023... It's ridiculous but things only getting worse. You cannot just bootstrap node+ts project, you need to spend days digging in endless configs to make it actually work with basic use cases.

Comment: @ViES 2023 June 30 , things getting worse . I have write flutter app for 1 year and return typescript today...

Comment: @ViES indeed, 3+ days wasted here just to get a correct configuration for 
`tsconfig.json`, `package.json` and module import convention that works and doesn't give me transpile/runtime errors -- all because whoever is maintaining these libraries is terrible at keeping things simple

Comment: Additionally, as I've discovered, when targeting `commonjs`, **tsc** will transpile `await import` (dynamic import) to `require`, but, when targeting `nodenext`, it will not. TS is getting more and more complex and unfriendly now :(, wasted days on the config too.

Comment: If you're using ESM, this might make things easier: https://github.com/ryangoree/tesm-node

Issues welcomed.