# What is the minimum version of Node that is compatable with TypeScript's node16 or nodenext module system?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

TypeScript supports Node's ECMAScript module resolution with the `node16` and `nodenext` [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#module) and [moduleResolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#moduleResolution) options. It's not clear if I must use Node 16 or greater to use either option. Node 14 has support for ESM and not much changed between 14 and 16. Experimentally TypeScript works as expected with Node 14 and `node16` but maybe there are edge cases that I'm not aware of.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html

The 16.0.0 change log lists a few removals and deprecations but no new features or changes to module resolution. I don't think these changes would affect typescript.

- (SEMVER-MAJOR) module: remove module.createRequireFromPath (Antoine du Hamel) #37201
- (SEMVER-MAJOR) module: runtime deprecate subpath folder mappings (Antoine du Hamel) #37215
- (SEMVER-MAJOR) module: runtime deprecate "main" index and extension lookups (Antoine du Hamel) #37206
- (SEMVER-MAJOR) module: runtime deprecate invalid package.json main entries (Antoine du Hamel) #37204
- (SEMVER-MAJOR) process: runtime deprecate changing process.config (James M Snell) #36902

Comment: Elaborate on *not much changed between 14 and 16*. Without digging further, "module" has many occurrences in the [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first saw this question, I thought this was a simple "yes, you need to use Node 16 with this." After doing initial research, that answer became foggy, but after lookin gat [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463698/why-we-need-nodenext-typescript-compiler-option-when-we-have-esnext), it again seems that you need to use Node 16 with `node16` and `nodenext`.

> Node 14 has support for ESM and not much has changed between 14 and 16.

I believe that since they have added that support, patches pushed for Node 10 and 12 have also allowed support for it, so that may change they way we approach this question.

In the end, I still believe that using Node 16 is the best option for you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding features support, you can take a look at [this matrix](https://node.green/) to verify that what you need works as expected. Regarding module support when you take a look at the documentation of NodeJS, some New features have been added like [in V16.17](https://nodejs.org/uk/blog/release/v16.17.0/) but it seems that compatibility is an important matter; moreover a breaking change would be indeed in the logs like the ones you mentionned above. Node 16.17 is a LTS so stability is of greater concern than intermediates. Hope that helps !