# Which typescript module settings for a library that is used in browsers and node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

There is lots of resources about this, yet it is easily confusing and I can't find any recent resources about this:

Today in 2024, I want to create a library, written in tyescript.
It will be used in React projects that use a webpack bundler. And the app will be rendered on the server (node.js) and in the browser.

**how do I configure tsconfig.json? Which setting do I choose for `module` ?**

**Context:**

The library already exists in CJS, but in a current big rewrite I am considering to upgrade to ESM, since we have issues in our apps that use this library (which are also CJS at the moment) with importing ESM only modules. And also, with CJS we can't make use of automatically split bundles when using dynamic imports in webpack.

**The documentation**

The typescript [reference for `module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#the-module-compiler-option) states that `es2015`,`es2020`,`es2022`,`esnext` should not be used for node.js

And it states that

> node16 and nodenext are the only correct module options for all apps and libraries that are intended to run in Node.js v12 or later

But does not mention if `nodenext` or `node16` can be used for browsers / bundlers like webpack as well.

What is it? Which should I chose?

I wonder if should I go for a split route of publishing a `/lib/cjs` and `/lib/esm` version, with `require` and `module` fields in the `export` settings of `package.json`?

That still leaves me with the question which `module` output setting to use in tsconfig so that both browser (through webpack) and node.js can use ESM. Or should I opt for one of these environments to keep using CJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to historical reasons, there are just too many combinations, but most are not required anymore. In summary, the following three rules are more than enough if you want to publish ESM-only package that can be used by both Node.js and browser:

- You package should use `"type": "module'`.
- If you are authoring library for Node.js **only**, then:

  - `"module": "NodeNext"`
  - `"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"`
- If you are authoring library for Frontend **only** via **bundler**, then:

  - `"module": "ESNext"`
  - `"moduleResolution": "Bundler"`

And, finally, one more **axiom** - The combination of `NodeNext + NodeNext` is a subset of `ESNext + Bundler`. The alternative way of saying this is that `NodeNext + NodeNext` is ESM with constraints as set up by Node.js module resolution algorithm. The most common example being the mandatory requirement of having file extension in the import statements e.g. `import {} from 'other.js'` in `NodeNext + NodeNext`. Such restriction does not apply in `ESNext + Bundler` mode.

So, if you are publishing for both Node.js (expecting to use without bundling) and for frontend (expecting to use `import-maps` or bundler), then you should use `module: NodeNext + moduleResolution: NodeNext`.

This ensures that TypeScript (and, other modern bundlers) respects `main`, `exports` declarations as specified by `package.json` [specification](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports).

Also, keep in mind that `"type": "module"` is important. In its absence, even with `module: NodeNext`, typescript compiler will compile `*.ts` files to `*.js` with CJS `require` statements and `*.mts` files to `*.mjs` with ESM import statements.

Finally, there is alternative way of thinking about it too! If you are using TypeScript as a compiler to compile your library, then you should use `NodeNext + NodeNext`. And, if you are using bundler, then you have a choice of either combination (although I still recommend using `NodeNext + NodeNext` due to strict semantics it introduces).

For more detailed, in-depth explanation of `module` and `moduleResolution`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473145/5723098) is a good read.